# Eclipse apparently picks up all but one projects from Git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, eclipse-kepler

I have a checked-out version of the [Redmine-Mylyn connector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/redmin-mylyncon/) open-source project. There are eight Eclipse plug-in projects plus two Eclipse features projects plus `.git/` as their sibling in the local file system. It turns out that after importing them as `Plug-ins and Fragments` (with options `Projects with source folders`) Eclipse recognizes all plug-in projects but `net.sf.redmine_mylyn` in the Git repository (i.e. it shows a corresponding suffix next to these project names in its Project Explorer view.)

So `net.sf.redmine_mylyn` is apparently not recognized with these apparent effects: it has no such suffix in the Project Explorer view and its `Team` menu list only `Apply Patch ...` (but no other option related to either Git or sharing). However, if I run `git status` from the command line e.g. on `net.sf.redmine_mylyn/build.properties` I can see that it very well also part of the same repository. The Project Explorer does not show the two feature projects at all.

What could be the reason that Eclipse (Kepler) apparently does not recognize one plug-in project in the Git repository and how could I make it do so?

**UPDATE**

Here is how the `.project` files are arranged in the file system (output from `find . -name .project`):

```
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.api/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.api-test/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.common/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.core/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.core-test/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.core.extension.timesheet_extensions_plugin/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.extensions.feature/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.feature/.project
./net.sf.redmine_mylyn.ui/.project
```

The `.project` files reference three or four `buildCommand`s (`org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder`, `org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder`, `org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder`, `org.eclipse.pde.ds.core.builder`)
and two natures (`org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature`, `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature`). The offending project is one of those which do not reference `org.eclipse.pde.ds.core.builder`.

And `find . -name .git` gives:

```
./.git
```

Comment: Could you show how the projects are laid out, e.g. to `find . -name .project` in the repository. Also, look if there's anything unusual in the `.project` files.

Comment: @robinst Done. I also had not yet mentioned that I had to import those projects into Eclipse (now added to 1st paragraph).

Comment: Hm ok, I don't see anything obvious that would exclude it from being recognized. Would it be possible for you to send me a private message with the link to your repository, so I can debug it? You could remove all source files if the problem is still reproducible with that.

Comment: @robinst It's an existing open source project and there is no harm in revealing it here. Please see last edit.

Comment: Next time, please include that information from the start, otherwise it's much harder to help -- other people might not have bothered commenting :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the usual *Import* > *Existing Projects into Workspace* wizard, I could not reproduce the problem. I don't know what *Import* > *Plug-ins and Fragments* is supposed to do, but it looks like a bug in there.

I recommend [filing a bug for Eclipse PDE](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDE) and add the link to it here. Be sure to include the specifics such as which repository you used. A high quality bug report contains: A series of steps to reproduce the problem (like you would write in a short tutorial), followed by "this is what I expected to happend" and "this is what actually happened".